# I'm having trouble undestanding WS-*

Tags: wcf, web-services

1) As far as I can tell, only transport protocol supported by WS-* specs is `http`? If so, is there a particular reason why WS-* doesn't also support other transport protocols ( `tcp` etc )?

2) Assuming we use a non-ws.* compatible binding/protocol ( ie non compatible security, transfer, encoding etc protocols ), how is this protocol specified within `WSDL` file? Meaning, is there some common understanding about how should non-ws-* compatible protocols be named/represented within WSDL files?

3) Do WS-* specs only recommend which protocols web services should implement for the sake of interoperability or do they also define some of these protocols?

thank you

**REPLYING TO user384706:**

> WS-* is a variety of specifications
>   associated with web services.

I assume WS-* itself doesn't define any of the protocols?

> They are implemented as extensions to
>   SOAP.

Could you elaborate on what you mean by *"as extensions of SOAP"*?

> WS-I Basic Profile is the
>   specification that defines all the
>   details that guarantee
>   interoperability among web services. A
>   web service fully conformant to WS-I
>   BP can claim to be able to
>   interoperate with any client.

Besides `WS-I Basic Profile` specification, are there any other specifications that define all the details needed for two web services to be fully compatible? Namely,  `wsHttpbinding` supports several WS-* specifications, but is there some common name that describes this set of specifications supported by a `wsHttpbinding` ( something like `WS-I Advanced Profile` )?

> A web service fully conformant to WS-I
>   BP can claim to be able to
>   interoperate with any client.

I assume web service implementing  `wsHttpbinding` isn't backwards compatible with `WS-I Basic Profile`? Thus, we can't claim this web service is fully conformant to `WS-I BP`?

**REPLYING TO marc_s:**

> 1) I don't think this is true -
>   several of the WS-* protocols are
>   definitely usable over netTcpBinding,
>   too - WS-Addressing, WS-Trust,
>   WS-SecureConversation,
>   WS-ReliableMessaging,
>   WS-AtomicTransactions and more. See
>   MSDN docs on NetTcpBinding mentioning
>   those WS-* standards.

But as other poster has noted, WS*- specs are implemented as an extension of `SOAP`, and `SOAP` only supports `Http`, since details of non-`HTTP` bindings are not adequately described by `SOAP` specs.  So how is WS-* able to suppport other transport protocols besides `http`?

> 2) The WSDL is in no way connected to
>   WS-* standards - it's just a
>   standardized way to express the
>   service methods and messages. It's
>   totally independent of WS-* protocols
>   and their implementations - you can
>   absolutely use a WSDL (and XSD to go
>   along with it) for your service, and
>   then use basicHttpBinding or something
>   else for your binding.

I know it's a vague or even a dumb question, but ... if I create a new protocol `T` and wish for my web service to implement it, is there some agreement on how I should specify it within `WSDL`?

> The WS-* specs typically defines
>   certain capabilities of your service
>   and protocol - not the actual service
>   methods and the messages they
>   exchange.

Does it also define any protocols?

BTW - Besides `WS-I Basic Profile` specification, are there any other specifications that define all the details needed for two web services to be fully compatible? Namely,  `wsHttpbinding` supports several WS-* specifications, but is there some common name that describes this set of specifications supported by a `wsHttpbinding` ( something like `WS-I Advanced Profile` )?

Comment: **NO!** SOAP does **NOT** support only HTTP - this is plain wrong. WCF offers SOAP compliant transports over TCP/IP, MSMQ - heck, you can even write a SMTP (e-mail) based transport for WCF and still be SOAP compliant! **REST** on the other hand (the `webHttpBinding` in WCF) supports only HTTP since it's tied very closely to the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)

Comment: Depends on **what** protocol T you want to define. A new transport protocol?? No problem - the WSDL doesn't make **any** assumptions about the transport. A message encoder - again, no problem - that's an implementation detail, no impact on your WSDL

Comment: The WS-* specs define protocols for specific aspects of your service behavior - transaction control, certain security aspects etc. WS-* does **not** define or restrict your transport protocol - how (over what transport layer and mechanism) your message gets from client to server is **not** defined in any WS-* protocol, nor does that show up in the WSDL file at all.

Answer (score 1):

WS-* is a variety of specifications associated with web services.
They are implemented as extensions to SOAP.  What this means is that they are using the SOAP messaging structure to implement their specification.E.g. in WS-Eventing passes the address to send the notification via a SOAP header.
SOAP is designed abstract to support other transports besides HTTP (*note*:HTTP is an application protocol running on top of TCP) e.g. SMTP and FTP, but only HTTP is supported by WS-I Basic Profile due to the fact that details of non-HTTP bindings are not adequately described by SOAP specs.
WS-I Basic Profile is the specification that defines all the details that guarantee interoperability among web services.
A web service fully conformant to WS-I BP can claim to be able to interoperate with any client. 
Web services standards have many ambiguities and WS-I BP, clarifies all this so as to achieve guarantees for interoperability. WS-I BP is the only specification for web services interoperability. WS-* are just mechanisms to perform specific functionality related to web services. E.g. how to send notifications to a web service

Comment: @user437291:I have edited my answer in reponse to your questions